# Javascript - Cannot get chrome cookies in extension working

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies

I am making a cookie deleter, adder and reader thingy, however, it seems like I cannot get it to work. My manifest.json is fine by the way. It is within the code.

Here is my code.
Background.js:

```
function getUserCookie(url, cookieName, callback) {
    chrome.cookies.get({ url: url, name: cookieName }, function(cookie) {
        if (cookie) {
            callback(cookie.value);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    });
}

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.action == "getUserCookie") {
        getUserCookie(request.url, request.cookieName, function(cookie) {
            sendResponse(cookie);
        });
        return true; 
    }
});
```

Example usage of it in content.js, it seems like it does not detect them (by the way the cookie I am trying is httponly, if that is necessary):

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "getUserCookie", cookieName: "example"}, function(response) {
console.log(response);
}
```

I tried many ways, like using other methods of doing it, I was excepting it to work but it did not.

Comment: What is `chrome.cookies` ? Official documentation suggests another way of reading and setting cookies. Have you check [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie)?

Comment: I did everything. Yes, I am losing my sanity... Also thats firefox, I am making a chrome extension

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is just a wrong sample code in your question but if you compare the caller code and callee you will see the following difference.

Caller:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({ action: "getUserCookie", cookieName: "example"},
```

but in the callee, you expect:

```
if (request.action == "getUserCookie") {
    getUserCookie(request.url, request.cookieName, function(cookie) {
```

i.e. the request is expected to contain `request.action`, `request.url` and `request.cookieName`. However, you are making a call with just `action` and `cookieName` props. I expect that `url` parameter is crucial for the `chrome.cookies.get` method to work. Try to make sure that you are passing it into the `sendMessage` and then into `getUserCookie` method.

Please let me know if this helps.